# Exception NJS-001. node-OracleDB

Tags: node.js, oracle, express

i'm trying to use nodejs and oracledb to connect to one of our databases.
Here is the code i'm using.
[image: Code]

[image: Exception]

Everything looks fine to me when comparing to the examples on 
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/select1.js
it looks right however i'm getting the exception below.

I am rather new to node so I may be missing something obvious. 
Can anyone shed any light on what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is syntax error in your code,

Try this:

```
connection.execute("select * from int_headers where ROWNUM=10", function(err, result) {
    // if else here
});
```